# How to get the desired output by using python code below?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The desired output that I am trying to attain is "B" when inputting .85 for score. My current output is "B" "C" and "D" using the code below. I apologize in advance if my question is not well structured, I am new to the community and coding.

```
try :
    score = raw_input("Enter Score:")
    score = float(score)

    if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0 and score >= 0.8 and score <= 0.9:
        if score >= 0.9 :
            print 'A'
        if score >= 0.8 :
            print 'B'
        if score >= 0.7 :
            print 'C'
        if score >= 0.6 :
            print 'D'
        if score < 0.6 : 
            print 'F'
except :
    print 'a suitable error message'
```

Comment: You need to use `elif` instead of `if`.

Comment: Why do you test for `score >= 0.7` and `score < 0.6` when the main `if` restricts the score to between `0.8` and `0.9`?

Comment: Thank you for your insight on my first question, I still much to learn in using 'if' and 'elif.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be careful when putting code into your question. Use preview to check if it looks correct.
Back to you question, you should check [control flows in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). Your code does not stop after first `if` - it goes further and check all conditions. If you want only one letter, you should do something like this:

```
try :
score = raw_input("Enter Score:")
score = float(score)

if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0:
    if score >= 0.9 :
        print 'A'
    elif score >= 0.8 :
        print 'B'
    elif score >= 0.7 :
        print 'C'
    elif score >= 0.6 :
        print 'D'
    elif score < 0.6 :
        print 'F'
except : print 'a suitable error message'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have much to learn in asking question and I will be sure to checkout control flows in python.

Answer (score 0):

One if after another will make your program to check all of them, they are inclusive clauses becouse one does not exclude the others, so you need the `elif` wich will exclusively scope the next executions, and an `else` statement for the default case wich will be `< 6` in your code:

```
try :
    score = raw_input("Enter Score:")
    score = float(score)

    if score >= 0.0 and score <= 1.0:
        if score >= 0.9 :
            print 'A'
        elif score >= 0.8 :
            print 'B'
        elif score >= 0.7 :
            print 'C'
        elif score >= 0.6 :
            print 'D'
        else: 
            print 'F'
except :
    print 'a suitable error message'
```

You should take a look over [python control flow](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: This way, the C, D, and F cases are not reachable, and A just in one very specific case.

Comment: @tobias_k, I was editting it with an explanation, just posted it without nothing by error, sorry about it.

Comment: Also, it is unnecessary to check for both `0 <= score <= 1` and `0.8 <= score <= 0.9`. The first statement will always be `True` if the second is `True`.

Comment: You could also use comparison chaining for the outer if (0 < score < 1) and the last elif could be an else, but apart from that, fine.

Comment: @DanielSanchez, may I suggest turning the final `elif` into an `else` statement? The previous statements guarantee that `score < 0.6` is always upheld by that point, so no need for a check.

Comment: @N.Wouda true about it, editing

Comment: Thank your insight on my first question. I have much to learn.